# 'Of Russian origin' v. 'of THE Russian origin'

Tags: articles

As far as my article-related knowledge goes, 'the' should be obligatory (as in "the Russian people"). However, I've seen both. Please help me sort this out. Don't forget to provide an explanation.

> China could import 120,000 tonnes or more of primary aluminum in May and the same in June, if the arbitrage persists at least in part due to post-outbreak economic stimulus, said Roman Andryushin, head of sales and marketing at Russian aluminum giant United Company Rusal.
>
> Around a third of this might be **of Russian origin**, he said.

(from [here](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/china-braces-for-aluminum-import-wave-as-coronavirus-recovery-upends-trade))

> For the last time MiG-23/MiG-27 class variable-sweep (Swing Wing) **of the Russian origin** will take to the Indian sky for the last time on Friday from the Jodhpur Air Base.

(from [here](https://www.financialexpress.com/defence/iafs-lethal-mig-27-to-big-adieu-to-the-indian-sky-on-friday-after-four-decades/1804568/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be *of Russian origin*. It is a set phrase, "of English origin", "of French origin", "of Mongolian origin", "of humble origin" and so on and so forth. See [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/origin):

> ANCESTRY, PARENTAGE
>   *was of humble origin
>
>   She is of French origin.*

You should note that the source of your second example with "*of *the* Russian origin" is [the Financial Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Financial_Express_(India)), an Indian newspaper in English. Excessive use of the definite article is characteristic of Indian English. Also the writer might have been under the influence of a correctly used phrase "take to the Indian sky/skies" in the same sentence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109222/discussion-on-answer-by-eddie-kal-of-russian-origin-v-of-the-russian-origin).

Comment: What's the difference between 'origin' and 'sky', in the context of my question?